# Google Play app review stuck between family policy requirement and inaccurate audience

Tags: android, google-play, review

I have a simple app which can be played by all the age group, but it also use leaderboard service in the game ( But this is not mandatory ), Any one can completely play the game with out login to google sign in. Now here is where i am stuck.

First they reviewed and said 
"My Game seems to be good for kids" so add the family policy requirement and i followed and i added all the age groups.

Once i did everything, they rejected saying i am using google sign in and its not allowed if i target the kids.

I cant remove that though, and its not mandatory to sign in, its upto user whether to use it or not. But i am ready to remove from family requirement and to change the target back. But then they reject saying my game is appealing to kids, its icon is animated character. WHAT I NEED TO DO ?

Their review system is broken i believe. What can i do now ?

Comment: unfortunately, [we are not the store](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Machine learning and AI is supposed to be helping others, but sometimes those are just unpredictable and seems to be illogical. Poor developers suffer. In my case, I am trying to update this game after 4 years, i wonder how other indie developers do the same.

Comment: i understand, but the point i was trying to make was that you won't find answers here (as that post explains) because we simply don't know, it really is between you and the store, as frustrating as that can be

Answer (score 0):

I'm Jacob from the Android Developer Relations team.

No promises on a different outcome, but we recommend you file an appeal using the link that was provided in your rejection email so we can take another look at this.  If you can't find it, you can also find details on how to appeal here:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en

Also and very importantly: do you mind sharing your APK name so I can pass it along to the Play team?  I'll ask them to keep an eye out for your appeal.

Comment: Thanks for the support, It got finally approved after a lot of appeal. I don't want to target my game for Kids or Family, But system was forcing me for that saying my store listing is actually good for family & Kids. Not sure how the system defines that though. Any way, i change my store listing and did some changes. Also even a small game mode which is very easy "kid mode" and when i removed it, they approved it. I refered other games where we need to put some lock for buttons if its for kids, i dont want to do that, instead i dont want to target the family session. Btw game is "Hapicuti"